# Including pygame in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, pygame, importerror

I'm trying to include a [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/) library in my Google App Engine aplication:

```
> import pygame
```

But I've got an import error:

```
> from pygame.base import *
ImportError: No module named base
```

How can I import it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. GAE has a very restrictive set of libraries you can use. Here's a list:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Comment: Joe, that URL just lists the libraries that Google pre-installs on GAE for us to use as developers. You can certainly add third-party libraries, I add half a dozen or more on every GAE project I create, none of which are on that list. There are other restrictions (see my answer) such as linking to C libraries that they don't allow, which is the reason this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of clarification: Joe's link is a list of 3rd party libraries that Google *already* has installed and available for you to use, but that's probably not why pygame doesn't work for you. For example, I use SendGrid and Flask in most of my App Engine projects and they works perfectly fine despite not being on that list (I just have to include them manually in every project I add)

As for pygame:

Libraries that rely on ctags or hook into other C libraries, are incompatible with how GAE does their thing. It's quite possible that some portion of pygame relies on third-party libraries (perhaps modules that load sound files that might use C libraries for playback). This will block pygame from being imported properly.

(update: Another post about a user having trouble running pygame on their Mac shows that pycame requires a library called pyobjc which very likely is not compatible with how GAE works, per my notes above)

I ran into this myself with a heavy math-related python package of which I only needed a small portion. It relies on a C library for maintaining precision with heavy variable typing. I ended up rewriting the small portions in pure Python using lots of int() and float() calls, and it worked perfectly.